# Check if an Integer Is a Power Of Two in C#

Tags: c#

What's wrong with my program?

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        bool check = isPowerOfTwo(255);
        Console.WriteLine(check);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public bool isPowerOfTwo (uint x)
    {
        while (((x % 2) == 0) && x > 1)
        {
            x /= 2;
        }
        return (x == 1);
    } 
}
```

}

I got error

> *An object reference is required for the non-static field, method or property.*

Comment: It's possibly worth noting that the algorithm itself could be improved. You should be able to use: `return x != 0 && ((x - 1) & x) == 0`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make method `isPowerOfTwo` static:

```
public static bool isPowerOfTwo (uint x)
```

Method `Main` is static, therefore you can only call static methods of same class within it. However `isPowerOfTwo` as it currently stands is an instance method, it can be called only on an instance of `Program` class. Of course alternatively you can create an instance of `Program` class inside `Main` and call the method of it, but it seems as an overhead here.

Comment: Or put it in its own class, instantiate it and call.

Comment: .. or call it this way: `Program program = new Program(); book check = program.isPowerOfTwo(255);` =D

Comment: @Andrei, thanks a lot. please, can you explain me why I need static method here?

Answer (score 2):

Other than pointing out that the method should be static, it might be worth knowing a much more efficient way of determining if a number is a power of two, using bit arithmetic:

```
public static bool IsPowerOf2(uint x)
{
    return (x != 0) && (x & (x - 1)) == 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options;

Make your `isPowerOfTwo` method [`static`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx.aspx) like;

```
public static bool isPowerOfTwo(uint x)
{
    while (((x % 2) == 0) && x > 1)
    {
        x /= 2;
    }
    return (x == 1);
}
```

Or make an instance of your class and then call your method like;

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program p = new Program();
        bool check = p.isPowerOfTwo(255);
        Console.WriteLine(check);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public bool isPowerOfTwo(uint x)
    {
        while (((x % 2) == 0) && x > 1)
        {
            x /= 2;
        }
        return (x == 1);
    } 
}
```

- [`Static Classes and Static Class Members (C# Programming Guide)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You forgot static...

```
public static bool isPowerOfTwo (uint x)
```